# numpy: how to get the maximum value like this in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a function in the numpy API that finds the maximum values of an array like this?

```
def fun_max(array,axis=None):
    return [max(array[:i+1]) for i in range(len(array))]

a=[3,4,2,1,5]
print(fun_max(a))
```

output:

```
[3,4,4,4,5]
```